# Sum cells values with a separation of 3 columns in Excel

Tags: excel, sum, formula

I would like to create a formula that sums all the values that I'm going to add in the future in some cells of the same row. For example, I would like to add cells D3,G3,J3,M3 and so on (separated 3 rows) in cell D1.

Best regards,

Comment: D3,G3,J3,M3 seem to be separated by 3 columns, not 3 rows.

Answer (score 2):

A good solution will depend on what (if anything) is in the intervening columns on row 3. A [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616) can produce some nice results by checking the stagger or offset of the columns but it isn't going to like text put into the intervening cells.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX(3:3, 1, 4):INDEX(3:3, 1, MATCH(1E+99,3:3 )))*NOT(MOD(COLUMN(INDEX(3:3, 1, 4):INDEX(3:3, 1, MATCH(1E+99,3:3 )))-1, 3)))
```

By switching to an array formula and a condition [SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57), you should be able to happily skip over any text values.

```
=SUM(IF(NOT(MOD(COLUMN(INDEX(3:3,1,4):INDEX(3:3,1,MATCH(E1+99,3:3)))-1,3)),INDEX(3:3,1,4):INDEX(3:3,1,MATCH(E1+99,3:3))))
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.

If neither ot those fits the bill, provide a little more information on the nature of what *not* to sum and more help can be offered.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

1) put **=SUM(D2:XFD2)** in cell D1
2) put **=IF(MOD(COLUMN(D3)+2,3)=0,IF(D3="","",D3),"")** in all cells from (D2 .. til the end)
3) put your data in D3 ....  til the end.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous' solution works if you only need to sum one row. If you need to be able to drag that formula down, consider using a flag in row 2 to identify every 3rd column (like Anonymous did) , and use a sumif formula to add the columns where that flag is present.

Answer (score 0):

1. Type

   ```
   =
   ```

   in the cell where your first result will appear (e.g. D1).
2. Click on the first value in the first row.
3. Press + on numpad.
4. Click on the next value in the next row.
5. Repeat steps 4-5 until you reach the last row.
6. Press Enter.
7. You can now select the results-cell (e.g. D1) and click and drag the small button to your lower right, across all the columns.

If you have a static reference - a constant in a cell that you do not wish to move use the $ operator, for example: $C$3 will not move column-wise or row-wise. $C3 can move column-wise but not row-wise and the opposite is true for C$3. This can be achieved in the Formula Bar, where you can also manually type in the function.